# The metric exterior of a massive object

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, boundary-conditions, stars

The only condition apart from perfect spherical symmetry that is required for the retrieval of the Schwarzschild-metric $g_{ik}$  is actually ($R_{ik}$ being the Ricci tensor, the contraction of the curvature tensor):

$$R_{ik}=0$$

But the Schwarzschild metric is indiscriminately used also for the outside of a massive object like a star or planet. In that case the retrieval of the metric should be formulated together with a boundary condition that is given by components of the energy-momentum tensor $T_{ik}$ ($\kappa = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4}$, $G$ being the gravitational constant):

$$R_{ik}=0\,\,\, \text{for}\,\,\,\ r>r_{star}\,\,\,  \text{and}\,\,\, R_{ik}|_{r_{star}} = \kappa (T_{ik} -\frac{1}{2}g_{ik}g^{mn}T_{mn})$$.

In the simplest case of a pure dust of mass density $\rho$ we would have $T_{00}=\rho c^2$ and $T_{ik}=0$ for $i$, $k \neq 0$.

Why is this boundary condition usually neglected ? Is $\rho c^2$ too small (for dust this might indeed the case) to have a sensible effect on the metric and under which conditions would that change, i.e. how massive must the object be to generate a boundary condition not to be neglected ?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity))?

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly: yes, I looked it up, it gives indeed the answer of the question. However, in case of the sun, inside the sun will be certainly govern another metric, because otherwise there would be black hole inside the sun which makes no sense. But then the inside metric has to be fitted to the outside Schwarzschild metric. This is always possible without problems ?

Comment: For a spherically-symmetric planet/star, I think the answer is yes (see m4r35n357's answer), but I haven't studied this in any detail. By the way, the assumption of spherical symmetry here implies no rotation. The metric outside a rotating planet/star is not the Kerr metric. There is no analog of Birkhoff's theorem for the rotating case, as far as I know.

Comment: @FredericThomas: yes, for any spherically symmetric matter distribution , the metric is Schwarzschild for $r > R$, where $R$ is some cutoff radius, note that the sun is neither static nor spherically symmetric, so, up to some higher order corrections, the real metric of the sun will differ from Schwarzschild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with the [Interior Schwarzschild Metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric)?  As far as I can tell it addresses all your queries.

Answer (score 3):

The interior Schwarzschild metric mentioned by m4r35n357 is a simple example of a more general class of spherically symmetric static metrics for a non-vacuum. This leads to the stellar structure equations and the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff equation which relates pressure to mass distribution and gravity for a simple model of a star. These calculations do indeed give a metric which goes smoothly over to the Schwarzschild-Droste metric when the pressure and energy density go to zero at some given radius from the centre of the star.